# How to get this type of page controller in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to use a page controller similarly as per the one used in the iphone transfering between different activities.I am not sure it being called in the android.How to do this any examples will be very much helpful.
Thanks.

[image: image here].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can achieve the paging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) using the ViewPager class from the [Android Support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).
As for the page indicator, you can do your own implementation, or give a try on [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) by JakeWharton that works with the ViewPager class.

Hope it helps, cheers!